# Questions on Möbius Inversion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, mobius-function

Ok so from the Möbius inversion formula, the book just assumes that its:

$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(\frac{n}{d})F(d) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})$$

- But why is this the case? Also some further confusions regarding Möbius inversion, in the book it says:

$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\sum_{k|(n/d)}f(k)=\sum_{dk|n} \mu(d)f(k)$, then we can reverse the roles of $d$ and $k$ to write: $\sum_{d|(n/k)} \mu(d)\sum_{k|n}f(k)=f(n)$

- Why does the sum suddenly become over $dk|n$? Also why is it possible to reverse the roles so that $d|n, k|(n/d)$ becomes $k|n, d|(n/k)$?

Comment: This is not [Mobius Inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) but more so about the properties of Dirichlet Convolution.

Comment: $d \mapsto\frac{n}{d}$ is a bijection from the divisors of $n$ to themselves. Möbius inversion follows from $\sum_{d | k} \mu(d) = 1_{k=1}$ and $$\sum_{k | n} \sum_{d | k} \mu(\frac{n}{kd}) f(d) = \sum_{d | n} f(d) \sum_{k  | \frac{n}{d}}\mu(\frac{n}{kd}) = \sum_{d | n} f(d) \sum_{m  | \frac{n}{d}}\mu(m)= \sum_{d | n} f(d) 1_{\frac{n}{d}=1} = f(n)$$

Comment: Ok I think I understand now, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using properties of Dirichlet Convolution: $$f*g=\sum_{nk=m}f(n)g(k)=\sum_{kn=m}f(k)g(n)=\sum_{d|m}f(d)g(\frac{m}{d})=\sum_{d|m}f(\frac{m}{d})g(d)=g*f$$

We see that switching $n$ and $k$ does not matter since multiplication is commutative. So it does not matter which function has which divisor evaluated.

Comment: ooo i see I get it now thank you !!